# Standard lib in embedded Jython

Tags: java, python, jython

I have the Java server app with embedded Jython. Everything works fine with old Jython 2.3 but recently a 2.7 version was released so now i'm trying to upgrade. First of all I've swapped old jython 2.3 jar with the new one, than I'v changed the lib scripts to the ones that come in the Jython 2.7 installation package. Using such starting setup, my app writes to log error that modules _jythonlib and _bytecodetools can't be found in jythonlib.py. I'm able to correct this changing these two lines:

```
from _jythonlib import *
import _bytecodetools as bytecodetools
```

with these lines:

```
from org.python.modules._jythonlib._jythonlib import *
import org.python.modules._bytecodetools as bytecodetools
```

Unfortunately another error shows up in log:

```
  File ".\storage\scripting\lib\random.py", line 43, in <module>
    from warnings import warn as _warn
  File ".\storage\scripting\lib\warnings.py", line 6, in <module>
    import linecache
  File ".\storage\scripting\lib\linecache.py", line 11, in <module>
    import os
  File ".\storage\scripting\lib\os.py", line 432, in <module>
    import UserDict
  File ".\storage\scripting\lib\UserDict.py", line 83, in <module>
    import _abcoll
  File ".\storage\scripting\lib\_abcoll.py", line 33, in <module>
    class Hashable:
  File ".\storage\scripting\lib\abc.py", line 99, in __new__
    cls._abc_registry = WeakSet()
  File ".\storage\scripting\lib\_weakrefset.py", line 21, in __new__
    return set_builder(_build, cls)(data)
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.python.core.PySetDerived.<init>(Lorg/python/core/PyType;Ljava/util/Set;Lorg/python/core/PyObject;)V
```

Do you have any idea how to fix this?